# How to work this setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm trying to launch a process each 4 seconds.
However, only one process is launched, and I don't know why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var timer;
    timer = setTimeout("displayStatemement();", 4000);

});

function displayStatemement(){
  alert("test");  

}
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: _I'm trying to launch a process each 4 seconds._ Try [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Comment: Use `setInterval()` and pass it the reference to the function instead: `setInterval(displayStatement, 4000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax is wrong. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer;
    timer = setInterval(displayStatemement, 4000);

});

function displayStatemement(){
  alert("test");
}
```

Comment: I don't see how the syntax is _wrong_. One _should_ try to avoid using `"displayStatement()"`, but it's not _wrong_ if they do.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var timer;
    timer = setInterval("displayStatemement();", 4000);

});

function displayStatemement(){
  alert("test");  

}
```

use setInterval instead of setTimeout